# Label being treated as a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div containing a label and 4 divs. I want some css and jQuery to affect the 4 child divs, but not the label, and so I wrote the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="score row-fluid">
    <label class="span8">Text...</label>
    <div class="span1"><img></div>
    <div class="span1"><img></div>
    <div class="span1"><img></div>
    <div class="span1"><img></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.score > div {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('> div', '.score').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if($(this).not('.score-selected')) {
        var $img = $(this).children('img');
        var point = $img.attr('src').lastIndexOf('.');
        var src = $img.attr('src').substring(0,point);
        var newSrc = src + "-hover" + $img.attr('src').substring(point);
        $img.attr('src', newSrc);
    }
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
    if($(this).not('.score-selected')) {
        var $img = $(this).children('img');
        var point = $img.attr('src').lastIndexOf('.');
        var point2 = $img.attr('src').lastIndexOf('-hover');
        var src = $img.attr('src').substring(0,point2);
        var newSrc = src + $img.attr('src').substring(point);
        $img.attr('src', newSrc);
    }
});
```

However the label has a pointer cursor, and it fires the mouseenter/leave JavaScript.

I've created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/styphon/DbwHg/3/), and interestingly it's not firing the JavaScript on the fiddle, but it is still being affected by the css.

Does anyone know why this label is being treated as if it's a div?

Comment: $('div.score>div').on('mouseenter', function() {

Comment: The code in question does not match the fiddle. Can you provide a working example of the problem using your real code please?

Comment: @andyb don't worry, it's all solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is giving `label` the pointer, and your mouse events are being called on `.score` as well as `> div`.  When you hover over the `label`, you are also hovering over `.score`

EDIT: I changed the logging on your JS fiddle, here http://jsfiddle.net/sEa5W/1/

The mouse enter isn;t getting fired from the label, but the mouse exit is being called when you hover over to the mouse label from one of the DIVs because you are exiting the DIV.

Comment: Add a background-color and you'll see that this is not the reason.

Comment: @TimEbenezer look at `bootstrap.min.css` - line 29 - `label{cursor:pointer;}`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about the bootstrap default css applying the pointer to the label.

Comment: It makes sense, as the `label` tag is meant to be tied to a form field.  Clicking on a `label` that has the `for` attribute will auto focus on that form field, so added the pointer lets you know its "clickable".  You're actually not using the `label` tag as it is meant to  be used

Comment: @cjd82187 I'm not using it as per the strict definition, but semantically it makes sense, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it is an idea (if you use html5) to use `<img data-large="path-to-large-image"` and use that in your jQuery selection.

```
<div class="score row-fluid">
    <label class="span8">Text...</label>
    <div class="span1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" data-large="fullsize1.jpg" alt="img1" /></div>
    <div class="span1"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" data-large="fullsize2.jpg" alt="img2"></div>
    <div class="span1"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" data-large="fullsize3.jpg" alt="img3"></div>
    <div class="span1"><img src="thumbnail4.jpg" data-large="fullsize4.jpg" alt="img4"></div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('div.score>div.span1').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if($(this).not('.score-selected')) {
        var $img = $(this).children('img');
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('data-large'));
    }
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
    if($(this).not('.score-selected')) {
        var $img = $(this).children('img');
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('data-large'));
    }
});
```

**edit** lol, just noticed I used large twice, but this can also be done with small or something. just data-anything. It was just a way to show you that you do not have to manipulate strings, but that you can use html5 data attributes.